# Apache Beam Dataflow Jobs started failing with: Workflow failed

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been running batch jobs for over a week now with DataflowRunner without a problem but all of a sudden starting from today the jobs started failing with the error message below. The workers don't seem to start and there's no log in stackdriver at all.

Anything I'm missing here?

```
Dataflow SDK version: 2.0.0
Submitted job: 2017-08-29_09_43_20-9537473353894635176
2017-08-29 16:44:24 ERROR MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler:101 - 2017-08-29T16:44:22.277Z: (54a5da9d57fd266d): Workflow failed.
```

**EDIT:** 
If I remove --zone=europe-west2-b from the batch run it works which indicates that there might be something wrong with this zone.

Comment: I think you have a typo on your tag, this is not a spring-cloud-dataflow question

Comment: cheers, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your job. It failed because it couldn't get quota to bring up the workers. Likely you do not have quota in that zone. This error is not handled back correctly, but it should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to look into the quota then.